# Pi2 as an USB-Switch to share his eth-connection

Tags: pi-2, usb, windows, ethernet-port, switches

I want to share my thoughts and questions about using a Raspberry Pi as an alternate Switch/Router or whatever.

First my problem is, I have 3 stationary PCs, all of them are connected to a switch (eth) to a localnetwork for ex. called network-A, all of these PCs need sometimes a change to another network (network-b). All PCs are running MS-Windows and switching the network isnt quite easy because they have to logout/shutdown for a correct change between A and B.

Is it possible to put the network-b eth-cable into a Raspberry and share the network over USB to the clients?
If it is possible, would MS-Windows accept these USB-Networks? (might be offtopic)

Comment: are you trying to avoid having to log into a domain? ... I doubt that changing the physical connection to USB will make any difference, you will still have to login

Comment: there are domains, thats correct. but for the usecase the domain isnt necessary. Its just an onlinetool that doesnt work in the normal network-A. Normally just contact the admin from this tool, but they didnt find a solution. So I thought, a Pi for serving the network-B could work.